# Eigenvalues of "product" of linear transformations.

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Let $T:H \to H\ $ be a linear transformation from a Hilbert space $H$ to itself. Consider the transformation $S: H\times H \to H\times H$, defined by
$$S(h_1,h_2)=(T(h_1),T(h_2)),\ \text{for any}\ h_1,h_2\in H.$$
If $\mathcal{E}(T)$ is the set of eigenvalues of $T$, then what can we say about $\mathcal{E}(S)$, the set of eigenvalues of $S$?

It feels natural that an eigenvalue of $S$ would be the product of two eigenvalues of $T$, but I have no proof for this claim.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the product. The eigenvalues of $S$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $T$.

To see this, note that if $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{0})$ and $(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{v})$ are eigenvectors of $S$, associated to the same eigenvalue $\lambda$:
$$S(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{0}) = (T(\mathbf{v}),T(\mathbf{0})) = (\lambda\mathbf{v},\mathbf{0}) = \lambda(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{0}),$$
and similarly with $(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{v})$. Thus, every eigenvalue of $T$ is an eigenvalue of $S$.

Conversely, if $(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w})$ is an eigenvector of $S$ associated with $\lambda$, then at least one of $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are nonzero, and
$$(\lambda\mathbf{v},\lambda\mathbf{w}) = \lambda(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = S(\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}) = (T(\mathbf{v}),T(\mathbf{w}))$$
and therefore, $T(\mathbf{v})=\lambda\mathbf{v}$ and $T(\mathbf{w})=\lambda\mathbf{w}$. Since at least one of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ is nonzero, it follows that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

The eigenspaces of $S$ are of the form $E_{\lambda}\times E_{\lambda}$, where $E_{\lambda}$ is the corresponding eigenspace of $T$.